# Calculating the averages of several vectors in R

Tags: r, average

I have four vectors:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(2,3,4,5,6)
c<-c(3,5,6,7,2)
d<-c(5,7,3,7,2)
```

I want to calculate the average so that I get:

```
average
2.75 4.25 4.00 5.75 3.75
```

Could anybody give me an advice on how I can do this?
Thank you.

Comment: If you run those lines of code, the fourth will give an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a matrix and use `rowMeans`:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(2,3,4,5,6)
c1<-c(3,5,6,7,2)
d<-c(5,7,3,7,2)
rowMeans(matrix(c(a,b,c1,d), ncol=4))
## [1] 2.75 4.25 4.00 5.75 3.75
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(...) mean(c(...)), a, b, c, d)
```

Solution with `Reduce`:

```
l <- list(a,b,c,d)
Reduce(`+`, l) / length(l)
```

Solution with double `sapply`:

```
l <- list(a,b,c,d)
sapply(seq_along(a), function(i) mean(sapply(l, function(x) x[i])))
```